# Where should I ask questions regarding smartphones (Windows Phone 7)?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have some questions regarding Windows Phone 7. Where should I ask?

Comment: Where do questions about dumb phones go?

Answer (score 7):

Nowhere as of now.  There's a [Windows Phone proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone) in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), you should follow & commit to it.

Comment: well you should search for other forums till then @Achu

Comment: @Achu: Programming questions go on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7), no matter the platform.  What is your WP7 question?

Comment: There are questions about things other than programming?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the title: Ask Android questions on [android.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/) and bring your friends :P

Answer (score 0):

A federated Stack Exchange site covering all smartphone and other electronic devices was tried. It was called [Gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets). [It didn't work](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/).

Now there are sites or site proposals about using most smartphone platforms:

- [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) for Apple devices (iPhone, also iPad, iPod, Macs, …)
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) for Linux-based mobile phones (Maemo, Meego, WebOS)
- [Windows Phone proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone) (targeting all versions: Windows Mobile, Windows Phone 7, and future versions)

If you would like a site about other platforms (Bada, BlackBerry, QNX, Symbian, …), [create a site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology).

There is also a proposal for [mobile phones in general](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11003/mobile-phones), and on slightly related topics, one about [e-books and readers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20794/e-books-and-e-book-readers) and one about [consumer electronics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064/consumer-electronics).

All developer questions can be asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) regardless of the targeted platform.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106257/where-should-i-ask-questions-regarding-smartphones-windows-phone-7/106259#106259), there's a Windows Phone proposal on Area 51, which has now gone on to public beta, meaning you can join the site and ask questions on it. As your question is about Windows Phone 7, you should use the [7.x](/questions/tagged/7.x) tag, along with all other relevant tags.

If your question is about general programming with a windows phone, you can ask it on Stack Overflow with the [windows-phone](/questions/tagged/windows-phone) tag. As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106257/where-should-i-ask-questions-regarding-smartphones-windows-phone-7/106295#106295), if it's about the Android OS, you can ask it on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) instead. If it's about general use of the Windows Phone operating system, it would be on-topic for [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

So, depending on the question, you can ask it on Windows Phone, Android Enthusiasts, Stack Overflow, or Super User. Keep in mind that some questions may be on-topic for multiple sites, in which case you need to chose whichever one you think will work best.